# Analytic continuation of factorial function

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

We know that the factorial can be extended to the whole complex plane except at negative integers and $0$ . But are there any theorems that allow us to do so ? . I know we can use the  Identity theorem in complex analysis to extend functions on open sets but how does that work on the that case ? or is it just the integral representation that allows this extension ?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is the product representation of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're looking for a way to 'naturally' extended the [factorial function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) to what we know will be the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) without first defining the gamma function and check it coincides (up to a translation) with the factorial function?

Comment: @GitGud , yes this is what I want .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the factorial function is defined only on the natural numbers, it can't really be analytically continued. Rather, there are two steps involved here:

1. Find an analytic function that coincides with the factorial function when plugging in a natural number.
2. Analytically continue this function to the whole (almost) complex plane.

For the first step, $\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\;\text{d}t$ does the job pretty well. For real inputs, it is a smooth curve that interpolates the factorial function in a nice way. Note that **this is not the only analytic function** that fulfills step 1 above. Just add any other analytic function which equals zero on the naturals, for example $\sin \pi z$, and you will get another one.

This function converges only for $\Re(s) > 0$. But it can be analytically continued to the whole complex plane, except at the negative integers. And this step is **unique** by use of the [Identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Comment: Thanks , this is helpful .

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: Glad to help!