# Reason for choosing a particular analytical continuation of the factorial

Tags: analysis, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/481985) I know the choice of continuous extention $\ \Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt\ $ is not unqiue.

But is that particular extension the unique best choice in some sense? E.g.
is it the only one that makes $\ z\mapsto1/\Gamma(z)\ $ entire, or does it minimize some uglyness-measuring functional?